# Google Awareness API cannot register fence on emulator

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-awareness

I try to update fence using following code:

```
AwarenessFence locationFence = LocationFence.entering(latitude, longitude, radius);

    Awareness.FenceApi.updateFences(
            mGoogleApiClient,
            new FenceUpdateRequest.Builder()
                    .addFence(LOCATION_FENCE_KEY, locationFence, mPendingIntent)
                    .build())
            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                    if (status.isSuccess()) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Fence was successfully registered.");
                    } else {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Fence could not be registered: " + status);
                    }
                }
            });
```

It works fine on physical device, but on emulator I get following logcat message:

```
Status{statusCode=unknown status code: 7503, resolution=null}
```

Has anyone any idea what might cause this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the location in the emulator? This page has instructions:

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator.html

Comment: Links are fine, but you should summarize the instructions.  This keeps your answer relevant even if the link becomes invalid.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, [7503 means](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/awareness/AwarenessStatusCodes#ACL_ACCESS_DENIED):

> ACL_ACCESS_DENIED: ACL authentication failed.

However, it seems like this is an emulator issue, because registering a `TimeFence` does work for me. Whereas Location- and ActivityFences don't.

```java
AwarenessFence timeFence = TimeFence.inSaturdayInterval(TimeZone.getDefault(), 0, 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

To use the Awareness API, you need:

GooglePlayServices (on emulator, Google Apis)

To Location Fences: Location services activated on device. If on emulator or stand device, I think you can fake it.

Seems that activity detect awareness uses a complex bunch of sensors like accelerometer, giroscope, locations, etc. So I don't now how efficient that can be on emulator.

And, finally, the device/emulator needs Internet connection! At first glance, you can think that Awareness location API is an offline service. **It's not**. If you check your Google Developer Console, you can see the awareness requests to Google servers.

The error, kindly clarified by @jmols tell the tale: the API is trying access the security chain for connect with awareness service, and failing. Probably because the device doesn't have network connection.

If you *have* internet connection on your emulator, double check your credentials for this API on Google Developer console.