# Mocking Google Awareness API

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, google-play-services

Is it possible to mock some elements from [Awareness API](https://developers.google.com/awareness/overview) in Android emulator? I don't see anything like that in the emulator's avaliable settings (except mocking location and and phone position).

I'm thinking specifically about mocking activity (staying still, walking, running, driving etc.)? I assume that weather data is coming by determining the location which I know how it can be mocked.

I want to write an application which uses this API's elements and want to test it easily during development process. This will speed testing process massively.

Comment: I suggest testing on a real android device as there are some features not supported by Android Emulator like Gyroscope and other sensors. If you check this [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38891252/google-awareness-api-cannot-register-fence-on-emulator), Awareness API works well on mobile devices but encounters errors on AVD.